# How to send email when user is created from BCC ATG?

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

On creation of new external user from ATG BCC, I need to include some logic like encrypting password and sending email to user. Achieved this functionality by extending GSAPropertyDescriptor class and overriding its getPropertyValue(RepositoryItemImpl pItem, Object pValue) method.

Problem is, this method is getting called only when we click on create button from "General" tab present in users section, but not on click of same create button from other tabs like "Commerce", "Orgs & Roles", "User Segments" and "Advanced".

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to override getPropertyValue of an item for this implementation. The right way to do this is to work with the formhandler that is responsible for saving the user. It is a bit tricky to find this formhandler. It will be in the atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository/ of the BCC instance. In this repository there will be lots of formhandlers configured for different purposes. You have to pick the one relevant for the user edit. Here is an example of what you might find there:

With this, you go to appropriate Formhanlder, like /atg/web/assetmanager/editor/profile/UserFormHandler mentioned here. And override that component in your module with your own implementation. Once that is done, you'll have the control of the action. You can do your work and pass on the control to super class (the original implementation).

Regards,
Jags

Comment: Thanks Krishnamurthy.I tried this solution.But,facing some issue while extending UserFormHandler.
/java/com/beacm/personalization/BEAUserFormHandler.java:12: cannot access atg.web.assetmanager.editor.TreeAssetRepositoryFormHandler
class file for atg.web.assetmanager.editor.TreeAssetRepositoryFormHandler not found
public class BEAUserFormHandler extends UserFormHandler {
       ^
Getting above error on server start up.There is no TreeAssetRepositoryFormHandler component in dyn/admin in path atg/web/assetmanager/editor/TreeAssetRepositoryFormHandler also in DPS-UI module in ATG 10.2 folder

Comment: Did you get this problem resolved? This seems like a regular java error with classpath issues than ATG specific issue. Ensure the AssetUI and other related modules exist. Please look at this link - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s2301appendixeatgmodules01.html